# Symbols and ones

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Here is an easy one. Enjoy!

Can you find a way to make the following expression false by only changing the order of the symbols?

> 1+1-1÷1x1=1

Comment: Are the ones symbols or only the operators?

Comment: Furthermore, how about the equals sign? May we move that as well?

Comment: It is meant to be an easy puzzle with only a small twist. Answering these questions would pretty much give the answer so lets just say that symbols are symbols and numbers and numbers.

Comment: @stackreader: Now that you've accepted an answer, would you care to explain what the "small twist" is?

Comment: small as in very small. It's just that some people would naturally try to change the symbols to achieve the result of 1, but in fact the only way to do it is to move the equal symbol to change desired equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here is a way

> $1\times 1+1=1 \div 1 - 1 \qquad\rightarrow\qquad 2=0$
>
>  or only moving 3 symbols (is less possible?):
>  $1-1=1\div1\times 1+1 \qquad\rightarrow\qquad 0=2$

Comment: Too easy was it? It was meant to be easy but solved within 4 views is a little bit sad haha.... Well as long as people are having fun it's fine by me. Unless it's too easy to the point of not even being fun.

Comment: I found it quite easy, but easy does not imply bad and hard does not imply good; plus it's good to have diversity. Others do not have to look at the solution I gave - maybe someone will give a solution with less changes...?

Comment: 2 moves is possible e.g. 1+1=1/1*1-1 which is the same as 2=0. Should I post as separate solution?

Comment: @boboquack Nice. I don't see why not?!

Answer (score 1):

My comment on @JohnathonAllan's answer that moves two symbols **that are not numbers**:

> $1+1=1\div1\times1-1\implies2=0$

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by just moving one symbol:

> +11-1÷1x1=1

Answer (score -1):

A trivial variation on Jonathan’s answer:

> $~1+1~~~~~~~\div1\times1=1-1 \qquad\implies\qquad~~~~ 2=0$

And, since you refused to nail down the rules,

> $-11+1~~~~~~~\div1\times1=1~~~~~~\qquad\implies\qquad-10=1$

Each answer moves only two symbols.

Comment: I suggest you stop being so literal. Symbols are symbols and numbers are numbers as the OP said should be enough for you to work out which is which.

Comment: I seem to have two options: (1) Take the OP’s words literally, and (2) read the OP’s mind.  “Guess what I’m thinking”-style questions are not welcome at [SE]; not even at Puzzling.  … … … … … … …  P.S. [Nick Dewitt](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45549/19765#45575) seems to have interpreted the OP’s ambiguity the same way I did — are you going to go negative on him, too?

Comment: To be fair to stack reader the puzzle is titled "Symbols and ones", my question was really just for double clarification. My guess is that the answer given was meant to be read how I automatically read it, "...so lets just say that symbols are symbols and numbers [are] numbers", and that was just a typo (if not it's pretty confusing).